# Using custom taxonomies in a query

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm using a plugin (IssueM) which gives the "articles" post-type a custom taxonomy called "Issues".

I'm trying to return all "articles" which have the taxonomy `issue-one` set (which is the slug name). But I cannot get it to return anything:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
array(
'post_type' => 'article',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'taxonomy' => 'issue',
'term' => 'issue-one'
)
);
```

I'm not sure whether the `taxonomy` field needs to be `issue` or `issues` so I've tried both but neither work. I have tried the slug name for the term e.g `issue-one` and also the written name e.g `Issue One`.

I have been instructed elsewhere that I need to use a `taxonomy query` instead, here is what I have so far:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
       'taxonomy' => 'Issues',
       'field'    => 'slug',
       'terms'    => 'issue-one'
    ),
 ),
```

Attempted the following, no luck:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
           'taxonomy' => 'Issues',
           'field'    => 'issuem_issue',
           'terms'    => 'issue-one'
     ),
 ),
 'posts_per_page' => -1
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the source code for [IssueM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/issuem/). I think the slug you are after is issuem_issue

However, there are two more taxonomies it registers: issuem_issue_categories and issuem_issue_tags

**Edit**

Try changing your args to:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
           'taxonomy' => 'issuem_issue',
           'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => 'issue-one'
     ),
 ),
 'posts_per_page' => -1
 );
```

This should all articles with the issuem_issue taxonomy slugged 'issue-one' attached to it.

Comment: I believe you are correct. the _categories is something different (I can give an article a category like 'Car Reviews' and the tags, again, is something that can be applied to the post. I will try with that taxonomy.